# Set builder notation, substitution of vars question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question on the following Cartesian product example in *set builder* notation:

$A \times B = \{(a,b) | a \in A \land b \in  B\}$

It's my understanding when values from the DOD (domain of discourse) are substituted for the variables in the right of the "such that" $|$ symbol and the logic is true, then the left $(a,b)$ will be true for the same substituted variables.  If no substitution causes the logic true, then the result is the empty set.  In this way we can build a set based on the truth of the right side form.

My question is how are values substituted for variables such that all the combinations are tried?  For instance above, are $a$ values substituted from the DOD and for each $a$ substituted, all the values for $b$ are substituted from the DOD.

Or is this substitution behavior left undefined for some reason?

Comment: There is no need of computation in set theory so you do not need to know "how" the elements of your set are found. Think of this notation as a specification, it is your role to prove things about the elements in this set

Comment: In a more constructive flavor of mathematics you would give a way to construct element of your "set" or any other axiomatic construction you are working with, but here in set theory it is not useful as there is no notion of "finding" things, think of it in a very platonician way, those elements already exist you are just selecting elements by specifying properties, no more.

Comment: @AlexandreSallinen I thought there was substitution taking place for unbound variables in set builder notation and when such a substitution leads to a true statement, the value to the left is added to the set.

Comment: No such things exist at least not in classical axiomatic set theory, the only theory that really deals with "variables" and "substitutions" are more constructive theories, lambda calculus althought not a fondational topic is what you are thinking of (somewhat) with substitutions.

Comment: At least in set theory, the subject are not "variables" but sets, there is no formal, axiomatic notion of variable in (most flavour of) set theory, thats a "meta mathematical" subject but clearly not in the scope of axiomatic set theory

Comment: @AlexandreSallinen by variables I was considering the unbound letters $a, b$

Comment: Bindings do not have a meaning in classical set theory, that's not a mathematical problem but a meta mathematical one, you don't need to assign values to "variables" as "variables" do not exists. $a$ and $b$ are sets, just like $A$ and $B$ as it is the only thing that exists in set theory

Comment: If you want to talk about variables, bound or unbound, scope etc, it is not strictly set theory but some sort of computable formalisation of set theory. I recognise that it may not be very evident depending on your background to "forget" the variables, but here you just assert properties of elements of your set, nothing more